# Valgrind on the CBE

Tags: valgrind

I need to debug a C application on the cell processor, and later to use valgrind for memory leaks. I checked on their website (supported platforms) but there is nothing about the CBE. Did anybody use successfully valgrind on the CBE? (Mostly for the SPE parts of the code)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard of anyone doing any work to port valgrind to support Cell processors. 
valgrind supports Linux/PPC, however the SPE have a completely different architecture.